# How can I set the text's color on the situation that the page loading new text when I am pulling down the page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I design a chrome extension to set the text's color on the page,but it just can complete some content.When I pull down the page,it loading new text.I hope this new text's color can be set like the text before.How can I set the code? In the mainfest.json I tried set the run_at,but it does't work. 
The second question is even I set some text use style.color ,but in the  I can't set the text's color? How can I set these?Thanks very much!

Comment: Change the color vía injected CSS, if possible, or use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: @Iván Nokonoko  Even I can set the color on the page, once I scroll the page down,it refresh new content after the content before, like the news list, everytime I scroll the page down ,it will appear someting new. Maybe I shoude judge the moment it refresh than I use function to set the current page's color again.But I don't know how to judge?

Comment: The appeared new content has the original color ever I set the page's color before.

Comment: If all the text elements (including the new ones) have a common class, you can create a CSS rule to alter that class (something like: `.textclass {color:blue}`) and inject it using [chrome.tabs.insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-insertCSS) or creating a new `<script>` tag with a content script. Once the class style is overridden, all new elements should conform to that.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is through [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi).

As mentioned in the documentation:

> Inserting code into a page programmatically is useful when your JavaScript or CSS code shouldn't be injected into every single page that matches the pattern.

Please note of the following when inserting a code into a page:

- Your extension must have cross-origin permissions for the page.
- It also must be able to use the chrome.tabs module.

  > You can get both kinds of permission using the manifest file's permissions field.
- Once you have permissions set up, you can inject JavaScript into a page by calling `tabs.executeScript`.
- To inject CSS, use `tabs.insertCSS`.

Samples of this can be found in the documentation. Aside from that, this similar SO post - [Chrome Extension to change text style of specific website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20583514/chrome-extension-to-change-text-style-of-specific-website) might also help.

Comment: Even I can set the color on the page, once I scroll the page down,it refresh new content after the content before, like the news list, everytime I scroll the page down ,it will appear someting new. Maybe I shoude judge the moment it refresh than I use function to set the current page's color again.But I don't know how to judge?